# Gradle dependency for sqljdbc4-4.0.jar

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am not able to find gradle dependency for the same. it would be appreciated if any one provide the dependency for sqljdbc4-4.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I have found the dependency

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0
```

Comment: this dependency is not accessible as of today